# Замена цвета текста/фона значений свойств PropertyGrid (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть контрол такой PropertyGrid. В него помещается объект, который расписывается по свойствам в этом контроле. Свойства, которые доступны только для чтения отображаются блеклым цветом. Ужасно иногда смотрится при определенных цветах фона ячеек.

В общем вытекает один локальный вопрос: *"Как изменить цвет текста ячеек доступных только для чтения?"*. И несколько общих:

*1. Как изменить цвет текста определенной ячейки?*

*2. Можно ли переопределить функцию отрисовки не всего контрола, а только его элемента?*

ЗЫЖ По разным форумам побегал, нашел только ссылки на готовые реализации PropertyGrid, но все они просят денег и предоставляют только триал версию. Для таких малых нужд, как "изменение цвета/оформления" отдельновзятой ячейки, мне кажется слишком.

ЗЗЫЖ уже начинаю задумываться, как бы этот грид не заменить обычной таблицей с двумя столбцами =) но, что-то мне подсказывает, что это не лучшая реализация будет =))

Comment: Посмотрите, как выглядит в `PropertyGrid` редактор цветов. Вам такого хватит? Вот так это делается: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml#EQFAC

Comment: Спасибо, это одна из первых страниц, на которую я наткнулся при поиске ответа на обозначенную проблему в гугле. Много от туда почерпнул - хороший FAQ, однако там не описывается проблема с закраской определенной ячейки. =( На текущий момент выкрутился с использованием картинки у тех полей, которые несут некоторую смысловую нагрузку... Далее все же буду переходить на WPF, там может получше дело обстоит с визуальной кастомизацией =)

Comment: @pincher1519 Однозначно лучше. Тем более WinForms уже не катит

Comment: Мне дизайнер окна в студии 2008 не нравится... в 2010 уже дело получше обстоит, глядишь в 2012 вообще шик будет =) Вообще, интерфейс разработчика для меня носит не последнюю задачу. Не люблю писать код программный в блокнотах.